# Cannot open include file: 'magic_enum.hpp': No such file or directory

Tags: c++, cmake, compiler-errors, conan

I want to write a test program for this lib https://github.com/Neargye/magic_enum with Conan and CMake.

This is my conanfile.py to create the pacakge

```
from conans import ConanFile, CMake, tools


class MagicEnumConan(ConanFile):
    name = "magic_enum"
    version = "0.7.2"
    # No settings/options are necessary, this is header only
    #exports_sources = "include/*"
    no_copy_source = True

    def source(self):
        self.run("git clone https://github.com/Neargye/magic_enum.git")

    def package(self):
        self.copy("*.hpp", dst="include", src="include", keep_path=False)

    def package_id(self):
        self.info.header_only()
```

And this is consumer

```
[requires]
magic_enum/0.7.2@jenkins/stable

[generators]
cmake
```

With this app I am getting an error:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <magic_enum.hpp>

// For example color enum.
enum class Color { RED = 2, BLUE = 4, GREEN = 8 };

int main()
{
    Color color = Color::RED;
    auto color_name = magic_enum::enum_name(color);
    // color_name -> "RED"
    
    std::cout << color_name << std::endl;
} 

D:\conan_test\consumer\main.cpp(3,10): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'magic_enum.hpp': No such file or directory [D:\conan_test\consumer\build\magic_enum.vcxproj]
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
 cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)
 project(MagicEnum)

 add_definitions("-std=c++11")

 include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conanbuildinfo.cmake)
 conan_basic_setup()

 add_executable(magic_enum main.cpp)
 target_link_libraries(magic_enum ${CONAN_LIBS})
```

Comment: That does not help (. It still can't find the header

Comment: No I want the header to be included from Conan cache. It is actually stored here: C:\Users\INT003167\.conan\data\magic_enum\0.7.2\jenkins\stable\source\magic_enum\include

Comment: (I deleted my prior comment.)  Interesting problem.  I'm not sure how to specify the cache location for the include path, but that seems to be the missing vital piece.

Comment: I found the problem. package method was wrong:  src="include" is redundant

Comment: I know you are just learning new things, but there is the official Conan recipe for magic_enum, which you can take a look as reference: https://conan.io/center/magic_enum